# jQuery is not loading on any page except front page - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I'm having an issue with a wordpress theme I'm building, in which jQuery only seems to load on the front page.

I've tried playing with the functions.php file, changing it from:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

to:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);  
function my_jquery_enqueue() {  
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');  
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);  
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
}
```

as I've read through Google, though it doesn't seem to change anything, no matter what I put in there I can't seem to get any plugins to work on single pages.

You can see an example of my single page that I'm having trouble with at http://cloggedcap.ca/customer-sites/cloggedcaptestsite/wordpress/projects/toxsic/
The images are supposed to open in a lightbox.  If you check out the root of the site at http://cloggedcap.ca/customer-sites/cloggedcaptestsite/wordpress/#portfolio and click on a portfolio thumbnail, it will load via ajax and the lightbox feature works fine.

Any ideas what may be causing jQuery to only load on the front page?  The single-projects.php page loads the header.php and footer.php file, where the wp_head(); and wp_footer(); are located.

Comment: jQuery is already included in Wordpress, you don't have to link anywhere, just enqueue it, and why do you not include jQuery for the admin pages, does it really matter ?

Comment: I tried this code from CSS-tricks.com http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/ though regardless, it doesn't work on the singles page, just on the front page so I don't believe that has anything to do with my problem unfortunately.